# Notificação com C# Framework, tem jeito?

Tags: c#, framework, microsoft-azure

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu usar notificação hub ou outro tipo de notificações com o C# Framework?
Se houver como alguém tem algum exemplo?

Comment: isso te atende: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification

Comment: Esse e para c# porem para html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se esse exemplo é o que procura: https://github.com/thiagolunardi/AzureNotificationHub

Para receber as notificações, basta registrar o app assim:

```
private async void InitNotificationHubAsync()
{
   var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

   var hub = new NotificationHub("NOME_DO_SEU_APP", "Endpoint=sb://NOME_DO_SEU_APP.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=CHAVE_COMPARTILHADA_DO_SEU_APP");
   await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);
}
```

E para enviar as notificações:

```
var hub = NotificationHubClient
            .CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://NOME_DO_SEU_APP.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=CHAVE_DO_SEU_APP",
            "NOME_DO_SEU_APP");

var toast = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01""><text id=""1"">Bem vindos ao VSSummit 2015</text></binding></visual></toast>";
var toastWithImage = @"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastImageAndText01""><image id=""1"" src=""https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-icon-set/512/Visual_Studio_2012.png"" /><text id=""1"">Bem vindos ao VSSummit15!</text></binding></visual></toast>";
hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast).Wait();
```

Como esse meu repositorio esta datado, veja se não houveram modificações na documentação do [Azure Notification Hub](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/notification-hubs/).

Comment: Pergunta Thiago: é possível eu fazer um Subscribe para que meu app Console ou Windows Forms receba as notificações, e eu possa executar alguma ação, baseado no que vier (como um push, por exemplo)?

Comment: Hum, notificação apenas apps Windows 10 recebem. Mas o que vc está querendo fazer é processamento de mensagens. Busque por Azure Event Hub. Será mais o que vc está procurando.

Comment: Vou pesquisar, obrigado pela dica.